# System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled

Tags: sql, wcf, linq

I'm getting a System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled from wcf service.

here is my code of Iservice.cs

```
namespace MyService
{

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1
  {
     [OperationContract]
     List<MyEmployee> FindEmployee(string uid);
  }
}
```

And code of Service1.svc.cs below

```
 namespace MyService
 {

   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
     public List<MyEmployee> FindEmployee(string uid)
     {
        DataClasses2DataContext context = new DataClasses2DataContext();
        var res = from r in context.MyEmployees where r.EmpId == uid select r;
        return res.ToList();
     } 
   }
 }
```

This code works fine if I change List to string and select one column instead of entire row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *List<<MyEmployee> to string

Comment: Did you try like this  : List<MyEmployee> lst = new List<MyEmployee>(); lst = res.ToList(); return lst;

Comment: Thanks Zaphod for answering. That solution did not work, still getting the same error..:(

Comment: Is MyEmployee serializable?

Comment: How can i check if MyEmpoyee is serializable? and how can i make MyEmployee serializable?

Comment: Check this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

Comment: MyEmpoyee is a table. Link did not say anything about the serializing tables.